# Reduction number of IF in my case

Tags: kotlin

I have too much IF in my method like this:

```
if (myObject?.name !=null)
first.text = myObject.name.bigThing

if (myObject?.age !=null)
second.text = myObject.age.bigThing

if (myObject?.surname !=null)
third.text = myObject.surname.bigThing
```

and 20 more ...

How can I shorten the code?

`age/surname/name` is type my own class `Big` with `id: Int` and `bigThing: String`

Comment: First of all, less code does not mean better code, however in this case we may be able to make this simpler.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be:

```
myObject?.age?.let { second.text = it.bigThing }
```

If you're putting the value inside a `TextView`:

```
first.text = myObject?.age?.bigThing
```

Answer (score 0):

Change each of them like this if you like it:

```
myObject?.name?.run { first.text = this.bigThing }
```

Comment: I expect an explanation

Comment: your code saves a few bits at the cost of increased reading complexity; if you want to go that way you should use `?.let { first.text = it.bigThing }`

Comment: *at the cost of increased reading complexity* I agree. But the question is about reducing the if statements so I disagree for this part: *saves a few bits*

Comment: @pwolaq as for the `let` way I agree, you can post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

One option would be

```
fun updateText(x: WhateverTheTypeOfFirstSecondEtcIs, y: Big?) {
    if (y != null) { x.text = y.bigThing }
}

updateText(first, myObject?.name)
updateText(second, myObject?.age)
updateText(third, myObject?.surname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact syntax in kotlin, however I would expect to be able to create a method something like this:

```
String extractBigThing(Big big){
    if(big != null) return big. GetBigThing() ;

    return null;
}
```

And call it something like this :

```
first.text = extractBigThing(myObject.name);
```

The basic idea is to extract reused functionality into reusable code, these can then be unit tested to increase code robustness.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`myObject?.name?.bigThing?.let { first.text = it }` etc for each line

or

```
myObject?.apply {
  name?.bigThing?.let { first.text = it }
  age?.bigThing?.let { second.text = it }
}
```

etc